# How to hide a console in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, exe, raylib

I am making something in Raylib C++ and every time I open the `.exe` file, the console and the raylib window opens up. How can stop/hide the console from opening up.

This is the makefile currently.

```
default:
    g++ ../Test.cpp -o Test -O2 -Wall -Wno-missing-braces -I ..\include/ -L ..\lib/ -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
```

My C++ file

```cpp
//@ Makefile: mingw32-make
//@ Exe: ./build/Test.exe
#include "include/raylib.h"
#include "include/raymath.h"
#include "include/physac.h"

int main() {
    int screenWidth = 1000;
    int screenHeight = 1000;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Ball");
    // void SetWindowIcon(Image "");
    Vector2 ballPosition = {(float)screenWidth/2, (float)screenHeight/2};
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_D)) ballPosition.x += 5.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_A)) ballPosition.x -= 5.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_W)) ballPosition.y -= 5.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_S)) ballPosition.y += 5.0f;

        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(Color {255, 255, 255, 255});
            DrawText("move the ball with wasd keys", 10, 10, 50, DARKGRAY);
            DrawCircleV(ballPosition, 50, MAROON);
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I provided the code snippet. I was expecting something that I can add into the makefile so hide the console. I think I heard from somewhere that `-w` does that.

Comment: `-w` disables warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-mwindows` to the linker flags.

Comment: I think this is only for Windows. Do you know what is the equivalent for Makefile in Linux and OS X? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Meniev Linux doesn't have this issue. No idea about Mac.